# sql server 2008 - French words break the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have french word like "Services d'organisation de séminaires" and I want to search word in SQL SERVER 2008. But the main problem is SQL SERVER give an Error because of string break.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'organisation'

can anyone have idea about this? My table stores french words.

Answer (score 5):

The apostrophe in `d'organisation` teminates the String literal in your query (apostophe is the standard delimiter), so you have to escape it by doubling it: `d''organisation`.

Comment: @MatBailie That would certainly be the better solution, but lacking context I couldn't give too much help in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

You should escape those single quotes. You can double them or use char(39).

```
Services d''organisation de séminaires
```

or

```
'Services d'+char(39)+'organisation de séminaires'
```